# solving html issue to display on same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html5 issue. currently the courses are displaying in 2 different rows. i need for it to be in one like no matter how many i add it keeps going to the left and but yes only 2 at a time.

something like this

1-------2

3-------4

5-------6

the current situation is like

1-------4

2-------5

3-------6

hope you could understand my point? here is the code

```
 <!-- courses Start -->
    <section class="section-space-padding">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                         <div class="divider dark"></div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="courses">

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

             </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="courses">

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="courses-item">
                    <div class="courses-circle">
                       <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                        <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                        <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

             </div>
            </div>

           </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- courses End -->
```

[image: Something like this - I want no partition of row]

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/fLonXCM642 it seems to work fine..

Comment: Did you try using all div classes ? (<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> is missing a few)

Comment: im new to html5 im really having issue @misdirection yes that way it shows ok but u see it is devided into 2 the second one starts from <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> but i do not want partition i want all to be together

Comment: @LoneWandereri need to get rid of that <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> from it so that i get what im looking for but it is just not happening

Comment: can you show the result you want.. this might help..  http://www.layoutit.com/build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified structure to fix order of items and added some CSS rules to get rid of space between columns:

```css
.row {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}
.row .col-md-6,
.row .col-sm-6,
.row .col-xs-6,
.row .col-sm-12 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!-- courses Start -->
        <section class="section-space-padding">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                             <div class="divider dark"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="courses">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                           <p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                           <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                           <p>Lorem ipsum 3</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">  
                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                           <p>Lorem ipsum 4</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                           <p>Lorem ipsum 5</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

                    <div class="courses-item">
                        <div class="courses-circle">
                           <i class="icon-book-open"></i> 
                          <p>Lorem ipsum 6</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="courses-content courses-color-blue">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                            <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                            <p class="morecontentdata more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eleifend risus sed feugiat faucibus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                 </div>
                </div>

               </div> 
        </section>
        <!-- courses End -->
```

Comment: yes exactly but just one row is what i want no partition in between i hope u get me?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. You wrote   `1-------2` (new row) `3-------4`. Now you want only one row? I don't get it :-)

Comment: i do not need multiple rows i want all in one row

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/NVUPZtxxOy